# How to pass variable value to stored procedure for fulltext statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I'm completely stuck this it:

```
SET @req='sometingToFind'
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(descr) AGAINST(@req IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This works fine but when I do the same into the stored procedure declaring like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `search_proc`(tn VARCHAR(32), r VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tn WHERE MATCH(descr) AGAINST(r IN BOOLEAN MODE);
END
```

And run it:

```
SET @req='sometingToFind'
CALL search_proc('mytable','@req');
```

I've got an error caused misinterpreting quotes.

```
> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mybase.tn' doesn't exist
```

I tried various alternatives with replacing **r** with **'r'** in stored procedure and others but all of these didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If ypu want to pass identifier names to the procedure and use them in query, then you should build a query as a string and then execute it using prepared statements.

[SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic table name problem strikes again. I personally don't like nor do I approve using dynamic table names in procedures, so my suggestion will be: **don't do it**.

Now on to how to do it: you have to create a prepared statement in your stored procedure and then execute it. That's how you'll prevent your table name to get quoted, and therefore interpreted wrong.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `search_proc`(tn VARCHAR(32), r VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN

SET @dynamic_sql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ', tn, ' WHERE MATCH(descr) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE);');
SET @match_against = r;

PREPARE stmt FROM @dynamic_sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @match_against;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: thank you! this works.
but a little mistyping there.
`EXECUTE stmt USING @match_against;`

Comment: If dynamic table names are not good how should I make search request throughout multiple tables? I use php+mysql environment.

Comment: Build a prepared statement directly from PHP then? The database shouldn't be using dynamic tables, reason I'm saying that this shouldn't be on db level is because it'll become a maintenance nightmare.